# CMake - Static library project is generating a different output consumer-side when imported with FetchContent

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I have a library project that I want to make publicly available via CMake's FetchContent and a public GitHub repository. This project's output is a single .lib file.

My problem: Whenever I create a testing consumer project and fetch the project via FetchContent_Declare and FetchContent_MakeAvailable, the .lib file that is built consumer-side is comparatively tiny in memory size and attempting to make use of it always results in a linker error.

Below is a minimal reproducible example

On the library side CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CMAKE_FC_reproduce VERSION 0.3.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Add source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
)

# Add header files
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES 
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/*.hpp
)

# Define the executable
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

# Fetch dependencies remotely
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  glm
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
  GIT_TAG           0.9.9.0
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(glm)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC glm)

# Define the include DIRs for the consumers of the library
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:inc>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:src>
)

install(DIRECTORY inc/ DESTINATION inc)
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake DESTINATION cmake)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config 
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  INCLUDES DESTINATION inc
)
```

This library is very simple and consists only of

api.hpp

```
#pragma once
#define  GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

glm::mat4 multiply_matrices(const glm::mat4& a, const glm::mat4& b);
```

and api.cpp

```cpp
#include "api.hpp"

glm::mat4 multiply_matrices(const glm::mat4& a, const glm::mat4& b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

And here is what I have on a testing consumer-side CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CMake_consumer VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Add source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
)

# Add executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Add include directories
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)

# Add static libraries folder
file(GLOB LIB_FILES 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/*.lib)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIB_FILES})

# Fetch dependencies remotely
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  CMAKE_FC_reproduce
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/diobat/Cmake_FC_reproduce.git
  GIT_TAG           master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CMAKE_FC_reproduce)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE CMAKE_FC_reproduce)
```

On the consumer project, I run this C++ code

```cpp
#include <api.hpp> // include the api.hpp file from the inc folder

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    glm::mat4 matrixA(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 matrixB(3.0f);

    glm::mat4 matrixC = multiply_matrices(matrixA, matrixB); // multiply_matrices is defined in api.hpp

    std::cout << glm::to_string(matrixC) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I try to build the consumer, the linker spits out an unresolved symbol error, with the following error message:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct glm::mat<4,4,float,0> __cdecl multiply_matrices(struct glm::mat<4,4,float,0> const &,struct glm::mat<4,4,float,0> const &)" (?multiply_matrices@@YA?AU?$mat@$03$03M$0A@@glm@@AEBU12@0@Z) referenced in function main

Comment: a [mre] would be helpful

Comment: `/Z7` vs `/Zi`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for the suggestion. I have now replaced the code I supplied with a more generic minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it

The problem was in the globbing of the source files in the Library's CMakeLists.txt

```
# Add source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
)
```

CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR should be used instead of CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR